# How to Create “Runnable jar” testng file for deployment?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, eclipse

I tried:

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();

TestNG testng = new TestNG();

List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();

suites.add("testng.xml");//path to xml..in src

testng.setTestSuites(suites);

testng.run();
```

like here:

[How to Create "Runnable jar" file for deployment?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17614/how-to-create-runnable-jar-file-for-deployment/17690#17690?newreg=f4d2de0034294369b65a3b09285ba2da)

I have this result:

Cannot find class in classpath:*first test on suite*

Comment: When do you get the error message?

Comment: when I launch the application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You have missed mentioning class file in main method,

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { mention class name here.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but it does not work;
Because I dont have a main class.
I have classes that dont have a main and several test classes
I dont know which class to put in set TestClasses (????).